# Proof in FOL with no CQ rule

Tags: logic, first-order-logic, predicate-logic, natural-deduction

[image]

I had the first completed but when doing its converse, since there is no CQ rule, I do not know where to proceed. Please help

Comment: What "CQ" means?

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA  Change of Quantifier.  The rules of Quantifier Duality.  $$\lnot\exists x~\varphi~\iff~ \forall x~\lnot\varphi\\\lnot\forall x~\varphi~\iff~ \exists x~\lnot\varphi$$

Answer (score 1):

1. $\lnot \exists x (P(x) \land Q(x))$ --- premise
2. $P(a)$ --- assumed [a]
3. $Q(a)$ --- assumed [b]
4. $\exists x (P(x) \land Q(x))$
5. $\bot$
6. $\lnot Q(a)$
7. $P(a) \to \lnot Q(a)$

> 8. $\forall x (P(x) \to \lnot Q(x))$

Answer (score 0):

As usual the key is to work backwards.

To introduce the universal, assume an arbitrary variable, $a$, then derive $P(a)\to\lnot Q(a)$.

To introduce that conditional, assume $P(a)$ then derive $\lnot Q(a)$.

To introduce that negation, assume $Q(a)$, then derive a contradiction.

To derive that contradiction under the assumptions of $\lnot\exists x~(P(x)\land Q(x))$, $P(a)$, and $Q(a)$, well...